# Azure In-Role cache ErrorCode<ERRCA0017> : SubStatus<ES0006> There is a temporary failure. Please retry later

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, azure, azure-caching

I am experiencing a very strange issue trying to get an in-role cache working.  I've only got 1 web role in the current deployment, and have set up in-role caching according to the MSDN docs and blogs alike.  I've looked at all similar questions on SO regarding the same caching error however no solutions worked for me and my situation is a little different.  I've spent hours googling, testing, and nothing seems to be working.

The project works fine locally, and when I push it to Azure for the first time.  In fact, if I am the only one on the website, it seems to work fine (although be it slow).  I started noticing while QA'ing with my partner that after a short period of time when we're both browsing the site it crashes.  At first it appears to be stuck, just spinning there and never receiving a response.  But after a while, we'll eventually get the YSOD with the error listed above.  Once the error occurs, all subsequent requests bomb with the above error, until I kill the w3wp process.  Then the entire process repeats.  The data we are storing in the cache is incredibly small for right now (well under the 8mb limit).

It seemed pretty intermittent, but after using the tool loader.io to test concurrent users, it consistently gets "stuck" (meaning starts throwing the above error) after a few requests were made and for all requests thereafter.

I have the AFCacheSessionStateProvider and AFCacheOutputCacheProvider configured for session and output caching as well.

After hours of trying to get the DataCache code to work (I even implemented retry policy via the Microsoft Enterprise block), I finally tried switching the calls of the Get and Put [wrapper] to use HttpContext.Current.Session rather than the DataCache object.  Alas, no more appfabric caching errors.  Loader.io was able to complete successfully running 500 concurrent users without 1 bad/unsuccessful connection, and I assume it is correctly caching via the AFCacheSessionStateProvider.  Also, the website appears to run incredibly faster after making the switch to the Session object over DataCache.

To give some brief context, we are accessing the cache at the start of each request via an http module (PostAcquireRequestState event) to load user information [permission claims among other data] for the current authenticated identity.

Although it is working with the Session[] object, we would still like to leverage the AppFabric caching api and eventually move to the new caching data service that is still in preview.  Why is this not working?  Also, any explanation for the speed boost after switching off the DataCache object?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem, I am currently seeing the same problem.

Comment: No, never got a response to this problem and had to move on so I switched to using Session (and the AFCacheSessionStateProvider) for my cache store.  I wanted to avoid session but since it's still using the distributed app cache fabric I couldn't find any disadvantages / differences to using it over DataCache.

Comment: This blog post helped me: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2014/04/29/cache-retry-fails-what-next.aspx